# What is the meaning of covered and not tracked in Go test coverage?

Tags: testing, go, test-coverage

I've started a small Go application to test it out and learn. In the main package I have a `main.go` with for example a function called `NewApp`.

In my test file I've called it several times, but in the coverage report its first line is marked as "not tracked". This function returns an `App struct`, but the whole struct definition is marked as "not tracked" to.

On the other hand I can't understand the difference between "not covered" and "not tracked". And is there a way to test the main function? I can't see the advantage of that.

My code is [here](https://github.com/fvosberg/mrsjenkins/tree/d81a3f3d5bc49e06e29a3e4a2bee60b05cbb9cfd).

Comment: "not tracked" just means it's not executable code, so there's no such thing as "coverage"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, so "not tracked" it is not considered in the coverage percentage.